# new List of Class object gives System.NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata, nullreferenceexception

I am upgrading my project from ASP.NET 4.8 to ASP.NET Core 6.0.  The code below works fine for ASP.NET, but gives an error for Core.  I am not sure why.  I have tried many different ways to solve it, but so far no luck.

The error appears when I try to navigate to its resource: `http://localhost/odata/Users`.

**UserService.cs**

```cs
namespace pal_data.Business
{
    public class UserService
    {
        public List<User> GetData()
        {
            try
            {
                var lsret = new List<User>();   // ERROR: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

                using (SqlConnection con = new(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnPort"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    var strSQL = "select a.*, b.RoleName from AppUser a inner join AccessRole b on a.RoleID = b.AccessRoleID";

                    using (SqlDataAdapter da = new(strSQL, con))
                    {
                        var dt = new DataTable();
                        da.Fill(dt);

                        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            var item = new User
                            {
                                UserID = int.Parse(dr["AppUserID"].ToString() ?? ""),
                                RoleID = int.Parse(dr["RoleID"].ToString() ?? ""),
                                Role = dr["RoleName"].ToString() ?? "",
                                UserName = dr["UserName"].ToString() ?? "",
                                Name = dr["Name"].ToString() ?? "",
                                Password = dr["Password"].ToString()
                            };

                            lsret.Add(item);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return lsret;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                // ...
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**UsersController.cs**

```cs
namespace pal_data.Controllers
{
    [EnableCors]
    public class UsersController : ODataController
    {
        private readonly UserService m_service = new();

        [EnableQuery]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<User>> Get()
        {
            return Ok(m_service.GetData());
        }
    }
}
```

**User.cs**

```cs
namespace pal_data.Models
{
    public class User
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string? FunctionResult { get; set; }
        public int ReturnCode { get; set; }
        public int RoleID { get; set; }
        public string? Role { get; set; }
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Working UserService.cs**

- this returns data without a null error

```cs
namespace pal_data.Business
{
    public class UserService
    {
        public List<User> GetData()
        {
            var lsret = new List<User>
            {
                new User
                {
                    UserID = 1,
                    RoleID = 1,
                    Role = "asdfsdf",
                    UserName = "sadfsdf",
                    Name = "sdfasdf",
                    Password = "asdfsdf",
                }
            };

            return lsret;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `var lsret = new List<User>();` should never give you `NullReferenceException`. It must be something else (another thread maybe?).

Comment: @MatthewWatson OK.  The error appears in the browser, when I navigate to the URL. It does not appear in the EXE's stdout and continues running.

Comment: Do you actually have blank `catch` blocks or did you just remove that code? MY guess is that one of your column values is `null` and you're getting the error trying to call `ToString()` on it

Comment: @DStanley yes, I do.  I hard coded a return and it works fine.

Comment: That line cannot throw an NRE. The error is happening on some other line. Unfortunately the catch is not showing you exactly which line is the problem. You need to check for null before calling `ToString` or use the null safe `.?` operator

Comment: Either temporarily remove the try-catch or [configure the Exceptions to enable CLR exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger).

Comment: @DStanley yes, you're right.  The problem was with the database query code in the function.  `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager` is not used in ASP.NET Core 6 anymore.  I had to fix my logging in the catches too, that was not working.  Strange that C# told me the error was with a correct line of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the code failed on the SQL query, the error showed on this line `var lsret = new List<User>();` for some reason.  Lesson learned I guess.  My SQL query is written properly now (without using `ConfigurationManager`) and the entity now returns properly.